# Binding checkbox in WPF by output of a method in a ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox, data-binding

im making a small desktop application using WPF.

I have a view that includes a listview with items, every element binds fine by the itemssource property and a {binding name} for instance.

However each listview item must have a checkbox. Whether the checkbox is checked is dependent on whether or not the item exist in a different list, meaning that i cant bind it by the model/datacontext. Is it possible to bind the isChecked property of the output of a method from the code-behind file? or how can i do this?

Comment: Might not have been clear enough regarding what i want to do. So just wanted to explain a little more...  i am using a listview with a datatemplate, the itemsource works fine. However the viewmodel contains a seperate list that have to be used when indicating if a checkbox should be checked or not, i am interested in taking a value from the current item in the listview, and then checking if it exists in the other list, if yes, then the box should be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have a listview and its itemssource property is bound to the viewmodel's collection. 
If so you should extend the object which instances are in that collection with a bool property. This property shall determines whether the instances is in the other list you mentioned and that property can be bound to the checkbox isChecked property.

Or you can do some nasty things in the code-behind file (iterate throug the listview's items and check whether the item is in the other list and look up for the item's checkbox and check it accordingly) but I strongly recommend not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what you are trying to do, you can use ValueConverter on the isChecked binding. 
On that method you can do a compare or test of the parameter exists in other lists. 
No need to break the mvvm pattern for that

iValueConverter usage and tutorial:
[Value conversion with IValueConverter](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)

Comment: Hi, sry if the question was unclear, - can i place the ValueConverter in the viewmodel or does it have to be a seperate class?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but if i understand correctly, you can try to use a `checkedListBox`. It can contains a list of checkboxes and you can iterate through it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) {

   if(....) {
   //here you can write your if statement or call a method whose return type is bool
   checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
   }

}
```